# Python: How do I find the average gap between successive primes?

Tags: python, average, primes

Here is my code:

```
primeList =[]

for x in range(2, 30):
    isPrime = True
    for y in range (2, int(x**0.5)+1):
        if x % y == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
    if isPrime:
        primeList.append(x)

print(primeList)


total_diff = 0
for a, b in zip(primeList, primeList[1:]):
    total_diff += abs(b - a)

ave_diff = total_diff / (len(primeList)-1)

print(ave_diff)
```

Can someone help me figure out where I went wrong? I used the range (2, 30) as an example since this code can be used up to any number. I don't really understand why I am getting the result that comes out, but I know it is always wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: what result are you getting and why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Please provide your output, and you expected output. The output I'm getting is totally correct. Are you on Python 2, by any chance?

Comment: I suppose this was a bad example. When I use the range (2, 20), I get the average difference to be 2, when it should be 17/7. Is this because it is rounded to the nearest integer? If so, how do I change it to not round?

Comment: Yeah try casting `total_diff` to float `ave_diff = float(total_diff) / (len(primeList)-1)`

Comment: As I suspected, you are on Python 2, no?

Comment: By the way the gap between successive primes is approximately [`sqrt(n)*exp(sqrt(n))`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html), so looking at the question's title : the answer could be ∞.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, as the output is 3 and indeed the average difference is 3. However, since the difference is always positive, you could simply do:

```
ave_diff=float(primeList[-1]-primeList[0])/(len(primeList)-1)
```

Because the differences cancel each other (that is, `(b-a)+(c-b)=c-a`).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, more of an improvement.  Since 2 is the only even prime you can halve the work you do testing primes by treating 2 separately and only dealing with odd numbers from then on:

```
primeList =[2]

for x in range(3, 30, 2):
    isPrime = True
    for y in range (3, int(x**0.5)+1, 2):
        if x % y == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
    if isPrime:
        primeList.append(x)

print(primeList)
```

For even more speed improvement, use the Sieve of Eratosthenes.